# Leap year check in Haskell, using pattern matching or bind operator

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, datetime, comparative-review, monads

One of the first Haskell puzzles on http://exercism.io/ is to implement a leap year check. I've done this twice.

Using pattern matching:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year
  | year `mod` 400 == 0 = True
  | year `mod` 100 == 0 = False
  | year `mod` 4 == 0   = True
  | otherwise           = False
```

Using the bind operator `>>=`:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = head $
                  [(400, True), (100, False), (4, True), (1, False)]
                  >>= check year
  where check y (interval, isLeap) = [isLeap | y `mod` interval == 0]
```

I'd like to know which implementation is “better“ / more idiomatic in Haskell. I am unsure whether I might have misused a t0o powerful concept in the second try, and the first try might just be more readable.

Comment: I believe your link should have been http://exercism.io/ but I can't make a one character edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is a lot more readable, whereas the second one uses a "hack". I would go with the first one, except that I would use `rem`, which is a little bit faster. And one could introduce some DRY:

```
isDivisibleBy :: Integral n => n -> n -> Bool
isDivisibleBy x n = x `rem` n == 0

isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year
  | divBy 400 = True
  | divBy 100 = False
  | divBy   4 = True
  | otherwise = False
 where
   divBy n = year `isDivisibleBy` n
```

That being said, for a programming challenge, your version is perfectly fine:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year
  | year `rem` 400 == 0 = True
  | year `rem` 100 == 0 = False
  | year `rem`   4 == 0 = True
  | otherwise           = False
```

---

The latter can be rewritten without `>>=` as list comprehension:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = head [isLeap | (interval, isLeap) <- classifications
                               , year `isDivisibleBy` interval]
  where
    classifications = [(400, True), (100, False), (4, True), (1, False)]
```

You could get rid of the "hack" with `safeHead` and `maybe False`, but that's left as an exercise.

If you really want to use `check`, remove the `y`. It just introduces an additional error source:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = head $
                  [(400, True), (100, False), (4, True), (1, False)]
                  >>= check
  where check (interval, isLeap) = [isLeap | year `rem` interval == 0]
```

Note that this shows perfectly that `>>=` is just `flip concatMap` for lists. So let's take advantage:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = head $ concatMap check classifications ++ [False]
  where 
    check (interval, isLeap) = [isLeap | year `rem` interval == 0]
    classifications = [(400, True), (100, False), (4, True)]
```

Which is easier to grasp than the version with `>>=`.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed comment. I think the second version with your improvements is very interesting as a pure exercise. But in production code, the first style might really be better.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer I forgot to add the difference between both: the latter gives rise to `isX :: [(Integer, Bool)] -> Integer -> Bool`, and `isLeapYear = isX classifications`, aka you _could_ change the list later on. That's not possible with the guard variant. Gurkenglas answer contains more details. As I said in my comment: a nice generic way would be `lookupBy :: (k -> Bool) -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v`, which is a great exercise by the way (although already somewhat solved by Gurkenglas).

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd go for the second sort of approach. It scales better. I'd eliminate four names and the hack like so, at the cost of `fst` and `snd`:

```
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = maybe False snd
  $ find ((==0) . mod year . fst)
  [(400, True), (100, False), (4, True)]
```

Comment: In what way is scalability an issue for leap year determination?

Comment: Obviously it's not. But not everyone can write the linux kernel from scratch, so sometimes you have to find artificial problems to practice scalable techniques.

Comment: *How* is it more scalable?

Comment: @jpaugh it contains a way to write `lookupBy :: (k -> Bool) -> [(k, v)] -> Maybe v`, which is a nice little exercise and a great generalization of `lookup`. But to be honest, I think that gets lost and is not that apparent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I feel bad not being able to “accept” both comments, as they helped me both. It's not like a bug fix, where there is one answer that solves the problem first.

Answer (score 0):

I did another variation of the “list version” of my leap year check. I think it's more readable this time because it doesn't work with these `(factor, boolean)` pairs. The intend what is going one should be clearer, also because I think I did better naming:

````
module LeapYear (isLeapYear) where

isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = hasOddLength $ yearIsDivisibleByList
  where specialIntervals = [4, 100, 400]
        yearIsDivisibleByList = filter yearIsDivisibleBy $ specialIntervals
        yearIsDivisibleBy d = year `mod` d == 0
        hasOddLength = odd . length
```
````